# Loading Scene's Assets in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, loading, kineticjs, assets

I just started my first JavaScript game project, and I am not sure what is the best way to load assets (images and sounds) in JS. The problem is I am using inheritance, so there is a problem with loading asset when needed ( example: Paddle extends Entity ):

Paddle:

```
function Paddle( layer )
    {
        Entity.call(this, layer);
    }

Paddle.prototype.SetAnimations = function()
    {
        this.image.onload = // INITIALIZE this.sprite using this.image
        this.image.src = "js/assets/paddle/blue/paddle_blue_idle.png";
    };
```

Entity:

```
function Entity(layer)
    {
        this.SetAnimations();


        layer.add( this.sprite );
    }
```

So the problem here is, when I am using Paddle constructor, the first thing is to call Entity ( parents ) constructor. Then Entity constructor use Paddle.prototype.SetAnimations to set image source and after load, with KineticJS i am creating Sprite using this loaded Image. But before this happens, Entity tries to add this.sprite to the layer ( and the sprite isnt already initialised ).

My question is, what is the best way in JS to load assets ( before every scene/at whole game startup OR @runtime using maybe event listeners?? ). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the size of your game / your assets. I personally load my assets before the game / at a loading screen. I use [PxLoader](http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/) for loading assets. I then store the images / assets in a big array in my game and access them when I need them.